# What is the best approach to serve high bandwidth traffic with AWS NAT Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops, nat, gateway

I want design AWS architecture like this, but not sure how to handle high bandwidth (>100GB) traffic.
A kubernetes cluster with lots of microservices , both frontend and backend. An LB in front of the worker nodes. K8s replica can scale high bandwidth traffic.
My question is where should I create the Kubernetes cluster? I know there is no bandwidth constraints in Public subnet, but AWS NAT Gateway has bandwidth constraints. What is the approach by big companies to serve high bandwidth through  NAT Gateway. Or should I put my K8s cluster in public subnet itself.?
Any help is appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the burst bandwidth of a NAT Gateway doesn't meet your requirements (currently 45Gbps), you will most likely have to configure a NAT instance.

(Bear in mind you can have one NAT Gateway per AZ)

The bandwidth of a NAT instance is dependent upon the the instance type you use.

There is more information about the comparison [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-comparison.html)

I would stay away from deploying your services in a public subnet unless it's absolutely necessary.